# ANTLR TemplateException was unhandled

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm using Antlr's string template capabilities and am seeing the following error:

```
Antlr4.StringTemplate.Compiler.TemplateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Exception of type 'Antlr4.StringTemplate.Compiler.TemplateException' was thrown.
  Source=Antlr4.StringTemplate
```

With the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messageTemplate = "<table style=\'border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%\' dir=\'ltr\' cellspacing=\'0\'><tr style=\'background-color: #f8f8f9; border: thin #e8eaec solid\'><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; background-color: #f8f8f9; border: thin #e8eaec solid; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px\'>New Order for Vendor: <strong style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%VendorName%</strong></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr style=\'background-color: #f8f8f9; border: thin #e8eaec solid\'><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; background-color: #f8f8f9; border: thin #e8eaec solid; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px\'><table><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>Order Number: </td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%OrderNumber%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>State: </td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%CustomerAddressState%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>County:</td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%CustomerAddressCounty%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>Municipality:</td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%VendorCity%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>Borrower:</td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%Borrowers%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>Product Family:</td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%ProductFamily%</td></tr><tr><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>Price:</td><td width=\'2px\'></td><td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt;\'>%Price%</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr> <td style=\'font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px\'><img src=\'https://www.americantitleinc.com/ati/Portals/0/WebLogo_V1.png\' width=\'250\' height=\'95\' border=\'0\' alt=\'American Title <br>Service Without Boundaries\'/></td> </tr></table>";

        var template = new Template(messageTemplate, '%', '%');
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"VendorName", "Vendor"},
                {"OrderNumber", "OrderNumber"},
                {"CustomerAddressState", "CustomAddressState"},
                {"CustomerAddressCounty", "CustomAddressCounty"},
                {"VendorCity", "VendorCity"},
                {"Borrowers", "Borrowers"},
                {"ProductFamily", "ProductFamily"},
                {"Price", 10.5d}
            };

        foreach (var key in attributes.Keys)
            template.Add(key, attributes[key]);

        var result = template.Render();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this error is extremely non-descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the template is HTML which contains a `%` sign which is also the character that is used for the delimiter.  Too bad the error doesn't specify that more directly.

Swapping the delimiter for a `~` fixed the problem.